# Passing UISearchBar.text to another function

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar

It's my first time working with a `UISearchBar` and so far it went fine, but now after clicking "search" I'm trying to pass the text to another function that handles the search.

```
[_searchModel searchIssueForTerm:searchBar.text inIssue:_dataModel.currentIssue];
```

This just throws me an error, saying:

> -[CFString copyWithZone:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7dee900

But when I use this, it just works

```
[_searchModel searchIssueForTerm:@"test" inIssue:_dataModel.currentIssue];
```

Why is this hapenning? In my `- (void)searchIssueForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm inIssue:(Issue *)issue` I store the `NSString` in another variable, why would it get deallocated then?

Comment: Not sure why this question is getting down voted though ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while I managed to fix it by just saving the variable somewhere else, seems it was getting lost along the way.

```
_currentSearchTerm = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:searchTerm];
```